# Regex the connectionstring and port

Tags: c#, regex

I want to regex this: `"localhost:65536"`.

These are the possible values/rules: string followed by a `":"` followed by an integer from 1 to 65536 if I am correct.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post the code.

Comment: Duplicate question: look at [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321458/regex-for-url-with-port-validation

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a regular expression for this? It's just as easily achieved with regular string manipulation options:

#### Regular string options

```
public struct ConnectionData
{
    public string Host;
    public ushort Port;

    public static bool TryParse(string connectionString, out ConnectionData data)
    {
        data = default(ConnectionData);
        try { data = Parse(connectionString); return true; }
        catch (FormatException) { return false; }
    }

    public static ConnectionData Parse(string connectionString)
    {
        var data = new ConnectionData();
        var parts = connectionString.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
        if (parts.Length != 2 || !ushort.TryParse(parts[1], out data.Port))
            throw new FormatException("Provided connectionString was not in the correct format of 'host:port'");
        data.Host = parts[0];
        return data;
    }
};
```

If you really HAVE to use RegEx:

#### Regular Expressions

```
public struct ConnectionData
{
    public string Host;
    public ushort Port;

    private static Regex FORMAT = new Regex(@"^(?<host>[\w.-]+):(?<port>\d{1,5})$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static bool TryParse(string connectionString, out ConnectionData data)
    {
        data = default(ConnectionData);
        try { data = Parse(connectionString); return true; }
        catch (FormatException) { return false; }
    }

    public static ConnectionData Parse(string connectionString)
    {
        var data = new ConnectionData();
        var match = FORMAT.Match(connectionString);
        if (!match.Success || !ushort.TryParse(match.Groups["port"].Value, out data.Port))
            throw new FormatException("Provided connectionString was not in the correct format of 'host:port'");
        data.Host = match.Groups["host"].Value;
        return data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+:[0-9]{1,5}
```

Also, in order to try regular expressions you can use, for example, [this](http://regexpal.com/) free regexp tester.