# Regex for finding URLs inside text

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to find bulletproof RegEx for URLs inside text using JavaScript (I'm replacing urls with `<a>` tags), My current was RegEx:

```
var url_re = /https?:\/\/(?:(?!&[^;]+;)[^\s:"'<>)])+/g;
```

It was working but didn't match urls with port (like `http://localhost:8080`). Does this RegEx will match all urls or I miss something too?

```
var url_re = /https?:\/\/[^\/\s"'<>]+\/?(?:(?!&[^;]+;)[^\s:"'<>)])+/g;
```

Or maybe there is shorter/better regex for urls.

Comment: Oh, regexes and general URLs, this is **way** harder than it seems: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: Your first regex: `/https?:\/\/(?:(?!&[^;]+;)[^\s:"'<>)])+/g` matches `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I found a regex here that should work.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6322319

Comment: It looks to like you are making this too hard on yourself . . . you are not just looking for URL's you are looking for **valid** URL's. Short and sweet would be to go with `var url_re = /https?:\/\/[^\s"']+/g;` (or something similar, based on what you are expecting as input) and just assume that the valid characters after the initial `http(s)://` form a legitimate URL. Unless there is an good reason to put `http://test.com` in a link and leave `http://test,com` as regular text, I think you are trying to tackle more than you need to. What exactly are you trying to use this code for?

Comment: @anubhava Try `'asdasd http://localhost:8080 asdasd'.replace(url_re, function(url) { return '[' + url + ']'; })`

Comment: @talemyn one special case is I don't want to match `&amp;` that's why I put this negative forward match.

Comment: @jcubic - Sorry, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the situation to see if there might be a better alternative to what you are trying to do (it's the software designer in me  :)  ).  I guess what I was wondering was, is there a reason why making an invalid URL into a link is worse than not making a link out of a URL that may just have a typo in it?  (Let's see what SO does: http://test,com )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use this regex:

```
\bhttps?:\/\/(?:(?!&[^;]+;)[^\s"'<>)])+\b
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wT2rG9